# How to put image in background in html

Tags: html, css

i am trying below codes to get image in background so i can write on it but image is not coming in background of row in table.
image and html page.

```
<table background="aj1.jpg">
<tr>
<h4 align="center" style="font-size:20; font-family:Monotype Corsiva; color:black;">My Home</h4></tr>
<tr>
<h4 align="center" style="font-size:20; font-family:Monotype Corsiva; color:black;">Enjoy every moment.</h4>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: You must include `td` tags inside `tr`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<table style = "background-image:url('aj1.jpg')">
<tr>
<td>
<h4 align="center" style="font-size:20; font-family:Monotype Corsiva; color:black;">My Home</h4></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><h4 align="center" style="font-size:20; font-family:Monotype Corsiva; color:black;">Enjoy every moment.</h4></td>
</tr></table>
```

background is not a table attribute, you need to use the style attribute to set a background image.

Comment: Still missing the `<td>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are applying `background-color` on `tr` then make `td` background transparent.

```
td{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: no idea where you got any of that from, especially since the OP has no <td> tags in his code

Comment: I did not observe that, I did not expect that kind of insanity in question so proceeded further to add solution that I have used.

Answer (score 0):

you do can with

```html
<table style="black">
```

or even with css:

```css
td {
  background-color: black;
  }
```